# How to get a slice data of a huge video file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsdata

I wanna load a video file into NSData,if I use dataWithContentsOfFile:,it will spend lots of memory when the file is too huge.
How can I get a specific data of a file with offset and length.
I need to upload the video file in pieces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [NSFileHandle](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsfilehandle_Class/Reference/Reference.html) then seek with [seekToFileOffset:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsfilehandle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileHandle/seekToFileOffset%3a) and read chunk of data with [readDataOfLength:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsfilehandle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileHandle/readDataOfLength%3a).

Answer (score 1):

This

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfMappedFile:<path>];
NSRange first4k = {0, MIN([data length], 4096)};
return [data subdataWithRange:first4k];
```

gives you just the first 4k of a file without loading all of it.

But dataWithContentsOfMappedFile: is deprecated in iOS5.

I suppose - WARNING: untested! -

```
+ (id)dataWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL *)aURL options:(NSDataReadingOptions)mask error:(NSError **)errorPtr
```

with mask set to

```
NSDataReadingMappedIfSafe
```

or

```
NSDataReadingMappedAlways
```

should do the job as well.

Butn that was new in iOS5.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an article that might help from [Cocoa is my Girlfriend](http://www.cimgf.com/2012/02/17/extending-nsdata-and-not-overriding-dealloc/)

> A couple of weeks ago Matt Long was having a problem with an app running out of memory. He had a ginormous data file he needed to load up and process, and that memory hit was more than the app could bear. It would load just fine, into an NSData, but before he could finish with it the app would run short of memory and die.